# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object error after migration

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework, migration, fatal-error

I migrated a php site from one Linux server to another. Its now giving following error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   /home/zhenyape/public_html/24diamonds/Library/Data.php on line 20

Following are the content of `Data.php` file

```
include(Zend_Registry::get('appConfigs')->application->path . 'Library/adodb5/adodb.inc.php');
$ADODB_FETCH_MODE=2;
class Library_Data{

    private static $conn;

    static function getAdapter(){

            if (self::$conn === NULL){
                    $host = Zend_Registry::get('appConfigs')->database->host;
                    $username = Zend_Registry::get('appConfigs')->database->username;
                    $password = Zend_Registry::get('appConfigs')->database->password;
                    $dbname = Zend_Registry::get('appConfigs')->database->dbname;
                    $dsn = "mysql://$username:$password@$host/$dbname?clientflags=131074";
                    //debug($dsn);
                    //debug(ADONewConnection($dsn));die;
                    self::$conn = ADONewConnection($dsn);
                    self::$conn->query("set names 'utf8'");
                    //if (!self::$conn) header('Location: /error/maintenance');
            };
            //self::$conn->debug=true;
            return self::$conn;
    }
 }
```

I have enabled same php modules on new server too. PHP version is 5.3 on both server. Zend Guard loader is also enbled.

> php -v
>
> PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2015 00:50:33)
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies

Any help will be appreciated. I am not a programmer.

Comment: is your mysql username/password correct? what is the value of self::$conn?  We need you to do some digging to find the root cause.